# Removing Items from TFramedVertScrollBar Correctly?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to create a `Previewlist` where i add an image and a remove button on top of it in `TFramedVertScrollbar` with this code:

```
var
PreviewList: TFramedVertScrollBox;
i: integer;
...
procedure TDashboard.AddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sImg: TImage;
  sBtn: TButton;
  sbit: TBitmap;
begin
  sbit := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    with sbit do
    begin
      Width := Image1.Bitmap.Width;
      Height := Image1.Bitmap.Height;
      Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
    end;
    sImg := TImage.Create(PreviewList);
    with sImg do
    begin
      Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
      Position.X := i * Height;
      Height := 60;
      Margins.Bottom := 2;
      Bitmap.Assign(sbit);
      Parent := PreviewList;
      WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.Stretch;
      onClick := PreviewItemClick;
    end;
    sBtn := TButton.Create(sImg);
    with sBtn do
    begin
      StyleLookup := 'listboxdeleteitem';
      Position.X := sImg.Width - 25;
      Position.Y := 5;
      Width := 15;
      Height := 15;
      Text := 'X';
      Parent := sImg;
      onClick := PreviewItemClick;
    end;
    i := i + 1;
  finally
    sbit.Free;
    Image1.Bitmap.Assign(nil);
  end;
end;
```

The Creation of PreviewItem works but not removal as on removing the PreviewItem the SystemBar does not responds(ex can't move or close or click) or don't takes mouse events and i have to click on other components in the form to make it responsive again.

I tried to two version of PreviewListClick first is below:

```
begin
 PreviewList.BeginUpdate;
 Obj := TButton(Sender).Parent;
 FreeAndNil(Obj); 
 PreviewList.EndUpdate;
end;
```

The Above Makes the SystemBar Not Responding so i did like this :

```
begin
 PreviewList.BeginUpdate;
 PreviewList.RemoveObject(TButton(Sender).Parent);
 PreviewList.EndUpdate;
end;
```

SystemBar is responding in this case and item is removed but there is one problem, after clicking on the Remove button of PreviewItem the PreviewList items are not updated.

For Ex. if there are four item in list and if i remove second one then item is removed but the list is not updated as the position of second item is still kept. now the PreviewList Looks like this:

**Item1**->**BlankSPace**->**Item2**->**Item3**

how to correctly add and remove items ?

Comment: Create a function where you update the Items position in creation and deletion time. then call it when you add or remove the Item

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout Well i found a solution till it shows any bug. Thank you for your time good night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing Object from content worked fine

`PreviewList.Content.RemoveObject(TButton(Sender).Parent);`